# Neural network modelling - y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=12)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, hybrid

I am developing a hybrid ARIMA - ANN model in which it I get an error stating "y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=12)".
The dataset consists of 84 data points - hence the 12 month periods in splitting and 60 in train/test-split.
I have tried with fewer datainput set which works, but when inserting the full data (as required) the coding issue still occurs.

It occurs from the following code:

```
len_training = 60
train,test = column_list[:len_training], column_list[len_training:]

predicted_list, error_list = [], []training_data = train

for t in range(len(test)):
model = ARIMA(training_data, order=(5,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit()
predicted_value = model_fit.forecast()
predicted_value = predicted_value[0]
error_list.append(test[t] - predicted_value)
predicted_list.append(predicted_value)
obs = test[t]
training_data.append(obs)
print('predicted=%f, expected=%f error=%f' % (predicted_value, obs,abs(predicted_value-obs)))

model = ARIMA(train, order=(5,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit()
training_error = model_fit.resid

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')


train_X,train_Y = [],[]
for i in range(0 , len(training_error) - 12):
train_X.append(training_error[i:i+12])
train_Y.append(training_error[i+12])



new_train_X,new_train_Y = [],[]
for i in train_X:
new_train_X.append(i.reshape(-1))
for i in train_Y:
new_train_Y.append(i.reshape(-1))
new_train_X = np.array(new_train_X)
new_train_Y = np.array(new_train_Y)


model.fit(new_train_X,new_train_Y, epochs=100, batch_size=2,verbose=1)


# test_extended = error_list
test_data = []
for i in error_list:
try:
    test_data.append(i[0])
except:
    test_data.append(i)



test_data = np.array(test_data)



test_X,test_Y = [],[]
for i in range(0 , len(test_data) - 12):
test_X.append(test_data[i:i+12])
test_Y.append(test_data[i+12])



new_test_X,new_test_Y = [],[]
for i in test_X:
new_test_X.append(i.reshape(-1))
for i in test_Y:
new_test_Y.append(i.reshape(-1))
new_test_X = np.array(new_test_X)
new_test_Y = np.array(new_test_Y)



predictions = model.predict(new_test_X)

Y = pd.DataFrame(new_test_Y)
pred = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
```

This is where I get the following error: "**y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=12)**" while refering to this line in coding: "error = mse(test[12:],pred_final)" the pred_final part.

```
pred_final = predictions + predicted_list[12:]
error = mse(test[12:],pred_final)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
```

I can see that the issue is predictions + predicted_list[12:] but I can't work my way around this...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The problem in the coding is stated lastly in the code - however the whole code in which the pred_final refers to throughout the coding has been inserted aswell.